# Difference between "Step ramp time" and "Step Duration" with Visual Studio test load

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I'm currently trying to test a site with Visual Studio load test. However, I'm not really familiar with that and I see really bad result so I'm wondering if my setup is correct. Basically, I want to simulate that 6 000 users comes to my site in a short period of time, so these are the property I put in my test:

[image]
[image]

From what I understand, I start with 500 users and then I add 500 new users every 5 seconds until I reach 6 000 where it stabilized. Is this a correct assumption ? Are these number realistic ?

Concerning my scenario, I have 7 of these that request some page of my site.

Comment: For your stated objective, I would suggest a constant, not stepped load pattern, with it set to 6000.
I'd also suggest a warm-up of a couple of minute or so so that the throwaway data is ramped up, rather than 6000 simultaneously starting from nothing.
That will ensure caches and suchlike are loaded in a running state before you make measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ramp time is the time that it takes to move from one step to the next.
During the ramp time, it distributes the extra load as it ramps up.

The step duration is how long it holds the constant load for the step, before starting to ramping up to the next one.